# debugging website using Chrome for Android (horror)

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, https

For 3 days I try to debug the website on android chrome, and I have no success.
I need to simulate https so the first thing is to set flags for Android Chome.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/user_data_dir.md

```
\data\local\chrome-command-line contains
--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure = http: // mypoor-unsecure-domain
--user-data-dir = /path/to/foo
```

But it just does not work! When I open chrome://version I can see 1st flag is set but 2nd is not.

This android debugging is driving me crazy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the URL bar go to

```
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
```

Enable it and be sure to add your IP with the port in the box provided